# How to send email alerts when a healtcheck returns 'degraded'/'unhealthy' in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, blazor, health-check

I have implemented healthchecks in my blazor application.

**Startup.cs**

```
  public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddRazorPages();
            services.AddServerSideBlazor();
            services.AddHostedService<PeriodicExecutor>();
            services.AddHealthChecks()
            .AddCheck<EndpointHealth>("Endpoint",null) 
            .AddSqlServer(Configuration["sqlString"],
                healthQuery: "select 1",
                failureStatus: HealthStatus.Degraded,
                name: "SQL Server");
            services.AddHealthChecksUI(opt =>
            {
                opt.SetEvaluationTimeInSeconds(5); //time in seconds between check    
                opt.MaximumHistoryEntriesPerEndpoint(60); //maximum history of checks    
                opt.SetApiMaxActiveRequests(1); //api requests concurrency    
                opt.AddHealthCheckEndpoint("API", Configuration["healthEndpoint"]); //map health check api    
            }).AddInMemoryStorage();
        }
```

```
            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapBlazorHub();
                endpoints.MapFallbackToPage("/_Host");
                endpoints.MapHealthChecks("/health", new HealthCheckOptions()
                {
                    Predicate = _ => true,
                    ResponseWriter = UIResponseWriter.
                    WriteHealthCheckUIResponse
                });
                endpoints.MapHealthChecksUI();
            });
```

To do this I used the asp.net healthchecks packages. What i would like to know, is if there is a way to send an email when the state of a healthcheck changes to degraded/unhealthy rather than having to manually check the /health or /healthcheck-ui pages.

Comment: [Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/health-checks?view=aspnetcore-6.0) say _"Health checks are typically used with an external monitoring service .. to check the status of an app"_

Comment: Agreeing with Stuartd. You can implement a HTTP Client that monitors the health of each service and send an email if any service become unhealthy unless you do not have any health monitoring mechanism.

Answer (score 2):

How about using a [WebHook](https://github.com/Xabaril/AspNetCore.Diagnostics.HealthChecks#Webhooks-and-Failure-Notifications) ? More details are available [here](https://github.com/Xabaril/AspNetCore.Diagnostics.HealthChecks/blob/master/doc/webhooks.md) .

This config section in appsettings.json will send an HTTP post to an URL you define:

```
"HealthChecksUI": {
    "HealthChecks": [
      {
        "Name": "Endpoint1",
        "Uri": "http://FQDN or HostName:Port/health"
      },
      /* Other endpoints go in here */
    ],
    "Webhooks": [
      {
        "Name": "Internal",
        "Uri": "/api/healthchecks/defaultnotify",
        "Payload": "{ \"message\": \"Webhook report for [[LIVENESS]]: [[FAILURE]] - Description: [[DESCRIPTIONS]]\"}",
        "RestoredPayload": "{ \"message\": \"[[LIVENESS]] is back to life\"}"
      }
    ],
    "EvaluationTimeInSeconds": 10,
    "MinimumSecondsBetweenFailureNotifications": 60
  }
```

In this case the POST looks like this:

```
    [HttpPost("DefaultNotify")]
    public async Task DefaultNotify(DefaultNotification defaultNotification)
    {
        _logger.LogInformation("Received default notification with message: {Message}", defaultNotification.Message);

        /* Other logic follows ... */
    }
```

And the object that gets posted looks like this:

```
using System.Text.Json.Serialization;

public class DefaultNotification
{
    [JsonPropertyName("message")] public string? Message { get; set; }
}
```